# ¿Por qué mi gif "cargando" no se muestra correctamente con ajax?

Tags: html, ajax

Tengo un gif que en teoría debía mostrarse antes de que se haga la petición ajax y debería ocultarse cuando esta petición haya sido resuelta. Así lo tengo programado (según mi lógica) pero por alguna razón no se muestra al iniciarse el evento onchange, o al menos esa no es la experiencia a la vista que da al usuario, se muestra casi casi al resolverle la petición e inmediatamente lo vuelve a ocultar, pero en el navegador se ve claramente que la pantalla se queda como pensando y ya que se resuelve muestra el gif e inmediatamente lo oculta otra vez.

Este es mi código js:

```
$("input[type=file]").on("change", function(){
             $(".gif").show();

            var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));

            $.ajax({
              url: "CargaArchivo.action",
              type: "POST",
              data: fd,
              processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
              contentType: false ,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
              success: function(response) {
               //alert(response);
               $('.gif').hide();
            }
            });

        });
```

html:

```
<div id="contenidoAjax" class="gif">  
        <img class="img" src="/Imagenes/cargandoPaginaWeb.gif" width="40%;"/>
  </div> 
<input id="file" type="file" name="files" tag-estatus="0"  tag-nombre="unNombreCualquiera"/>
```

**EDIT:** Parece que no me he dado mucho a entender, pido una disculpa; con "Tengo un gif que en teoría debía mostrarse antes de que se haga la petición aja" es literalmente eso, antes de que se haga la petición ajax, o sea en cuanto se cambie el valor del input file y antes que se haga la petición ajax. Le he puesto un sleep a mi servidor y el "cargando" se ve muy bonito y todo, pero sale cuando la petición ajax se está realizando, yo quiero que salga cuando se cambia el valor del input file ya que si inicio el "cargando" cuando la petición ajax se inicia la pantalla del cliente queda intermitente unos 3 o 4 segundos antes que se haga la petición ajax (que son los que quiero cubrir con el gif).

¿Qué está pasando en esos 3 o 4 segundos antes de que se inicie la petición ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El hide deberías hacerlo un vez se ha completado el ajax, en lugar de en el onsuccess, ya que si la respuesta es rápida aunque no haya terminado todo va a intentar ocultarlo. Prueba así a ver si consigues el efecto esperado.

```
$("input[type=file]").on("change", function(){
             $(".gif").show();

            var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));

            $.ajax({
              url: "CargaArchivo.action",
              type: "POST",
              data: fd,
              processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
              contentType: false ,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
              success: function(response) {
               //alert(response);
              },
              complete: function(){
               $('.gif').hide();
              }
            }
            });

        });
```

Sino, otra opción es asociarlo a inicio y final de los eventos ajax.

```
$('.gif').bind('ajaxStart', function(){
    $(this).show();
}).bind('ajaxStop', function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Si la versión de jquery es a partir de 1.9, la última parte se haría de este modo:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $(".gif").show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $(".gif").hide();
});
```

**Edición para ejecutar antes la imagen**

Como parece que tarda en detectar el evento onchange, puedes probar a añadir en la etiqueta del select una función onclick que muestre el gif (el click debería ser anterior al onchange), y luego lo escondes cuando se haya ejecutado el ajax.

Comment: Hola, Carmen, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Solo aclarando, es correcto que 'complete' esté dentro de 'success'?

Comment: No, uy se me ha ido una línea, lo edito que va justo a continuación :), perdón

Comment: Hola, Camer. Tu respuesta es excelente para que mi gif se muestre al iniciarse la petición, pero lo quiero realmente cuando el input file cambie de valor, por alguna razón el explorador se queda como "pensando" quiero suponer que procesa el archivo file o qué sé yo pero ese tiempo es el que también quiero cubrir con el gif.

Comment: El problema puede ser porque al tratarse de un campo tipo file tarda un tiempo en abrir el explorador para ver los archivos y hasta que no seleccionas uno no entra en el evento onchange, ¿voy bien encaminada? En este caso puedes probar a añadir en la etiqueta del select una función onclick que muestre el gif (el click debería ser anterior al onchange), y luego lo escondes cuando se haya ejecutado el ajax.

Comment: La intermitente del explorador es cuando ya seleccionaste el archivo pues al seleccionar lanzas el evento onchange, no antes. A eso me refiero, aún cuando seleccionas el nuevo archivo y en teoría se lanza el onchange debería aparecer el gif  pero no lo hace hasta dentro de 4 segundos aprox

Comment: Y tu propuesta sobre el click la voy a probar, no lo había pensado! ahhaa gracias, ahorita te platico como salió xD

Comment: HAHAHAH no es lo que esperaba pero estoy satisfecho xD Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te haya servido :)

Comment: Puedes agregar esa parte del click en tu respuesta, porfa

Comment: Editado, así queda completa la respuesta.

Comment: Oye, Carmen; y si el usuario da "cancelar" a la ventana que sale para elegir el archivo a subir cómo escondo el "cargando" que lancé al click? xD

Comment: Se me ocurre que como si cancela no va a entrar en el onchange, puedes preguntar si el input file está vacío, que es lo que pasa cuando cancela, y haces el hide.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_show.asp), el método `show` tiene 3 parámetros:

> $(selector).show(speed,easing,callback)

y el parámetro speed tiene un valor default de 400 milisegundos.

Entonces puede ser que cuando el método recién se terminó de ejecutar la petición ajax ya finalizó.

También puedes ligar el método al inicio de la petición ajax de esta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
       $("#loading").show();
   }).ajaxStop(function () {
       $("#loading").hide();
   });
});
```

Por otro lado, puedes utilizar una librería llamada [jquery-loading](https://github.com/CarlosBonetti/jquery-loading), fácil de usar y con animaciones personalizables

Comment: Hola, Rene, he actualizado mi pregunta para ponerla más clara